# Access element, which contains current <script>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got following page:

```
<div><script>AddSomeContent(??, 1)</script></div>
<div><script>AddSomeContent(??, 2)</script></div>
```

I need to replace the `??` with the surrounding `<div>` DOM object, so the function `AddSomeContent` can modify it. Is there any oportunity to do this?

Before any other comments: I don't have any other option. I'm already trying to hack some existing page, and only thing I can control is content of the `<script>`.

I'm using jquery, but I can change it.

Edit: for clarification. `AddSomeContent` looks like:

```
function AddSomeContent(somediv, parameter)
{
     $(somediv).append('there goes some data, that I dynamically create from some stuff depending on the parameter');
}
```

And I want to first div contain result with `parameter = 1`, second div `parameter=2`

Comment: confused on what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Do the DIVs have any form of unique identifier? @PatrickScott it appears he's trying to pass the div object that contains the script tag as an argument in AddSomeContent()

Comment: @Patrick Scott He's trying something like <div><?=$something?></div> in HTML & JS. user1090190 no, that's the problem.

Comment: @PatrickScott, see my edit. Is it more clear now?

Comment: @user1090190, if they had, I can access them with `$('#ID')`. Unfortunately they don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this, though it's somewhat of a hack:

```
(function() {
  var scr = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
      parent = scr[scr.length - 1].parentNode;
  // parent is the parent node of the last script on the page
})();
```

If you've got code in `<script>` tags like that, then when it runs the last script on the page will be the one that contained it.

Comment: But what if you don't know, if the script tag will be the last?

Comment: The browser runs the code in each `<script>` tag immediately, before moving forward in the document. That is, if there are two `<script>` tags as in the sample code in the question, then when the code in the first one runs, the second `<script>` will not yet be part of the DOM.

Comment: You, sir, never cease to amaze me with your wizardy. Pointy fan club member #1.

Comment: Ha ha well this is not the sort of thing I would rely on; it should work, but it's pretty flimsy. If I were a browser maintainer I would be sad over the fact that people do things like this :-)

Comment: @Pointy, you are a genius. I would never realize that knowledge of running `<script>s` in serial can be hacked like this.

Comment: It works for me now, and it should probably work for the guy desperately wanting this hack, and this is all I care about at this point. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I remember this from a previous question. The number of scripts on the page is incremented by 1 with each script that is processed, and they are processed in order. So this function will get the current script number:

```
function countScripts() {
    return document.scripts.length;
}
```

Then you can go get the parentNode of that script:

```
var thisScriptParent = document.scripts[countScripts()].parentNode;
```